# Xamarin Forms MasterDetailPage button padding issue in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm currently learning Xamarin Forms and I have a small graphic issue.
I have to fit the height of all the buttons to 100% (based on Navigation bar).
Actually Xamarin cut some pixels in the bottom for the hamburger icon and the "three dots" icon is not set to 100% height.

**I'm using the default template Master-Detail installed by Visual Studio, the issue it can be reproduced by creating the Master-Detail template in your app**

[image: Click here to see the example]

Comment: What do you mean by 'unusual' and what do you want us to do with this? Please [edit] the question containing a detailed description of what is currently wrong and how you would like it fixed, as well as the code to produce this, this is called a [mcve].

Comment: Edited. Remove -1 please

Comment: I have created a blank xamarin uwp app with master detail page, unfortunately, hamburger icon and the "three dots" icon is set to 100% height.  Could you share a mini sample that could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT : Check this project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JFE3O224IpuafzCBX3upohdddZs2DvSM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, I will test your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue, The problem occurs in UWP **17763** target version. It looks like a bug. I will report this. Currently, you could set your UWP target version as **17134** to avoid this behavior.

This is bug report [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5661).

Comment: [Not assigned yet](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/projects/20#card-20032570) and *not* "In Progress" still...